# Erro de cors em aplicação dotnet core + react web app

Tags: react, asp.net-core, nginx, cors, amazon-aws

Estou com um problema de aplicação que quando envio arquivos via POST e a imagem for maior em mb ocorre erro de cors, imagens de poucos kb funcionam normalmente.
**Dotnet core api**
Na api eu já adicionei o cors e adicionei as permissões no configure services:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
          .AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          //.AllowCredentials())
          ));
```

e no configure:

```
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Testando via postman, independente do tamanho das imagens, não ocorre o erro.

Com imagem pequena e que não ocorre o erro:
[image: response sem erro com imagem pequena]

Com imagem grande e que ocorre o erro:
[image: Response com erro em arquivo maior]

**Código React com Axios**

```
api
  .post(`anuncio/${anuncio.idImovel}/imagem`, data, {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      authorization: `bearer ${getToken()}`,
    },
    onUploadProgress: (e) => {
      const progress = parseInt(Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total));
      this.updateFile(uploadedFile.id, {
        progress: progress,
      });
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    this.updateFile(uploadedFile.id, {
      uploaded: true,
      imagemPrincipal: !principal && index === 0,
      id: response.data.id.toString(),
      href: response.data.link.href,
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    this.updateFile(uploadedFile.id, {
      error: true,
      uploaded: true,
    });
  });
```

};

**Dados de ambiente**
Servidor linux hospedado na AWS.
Utilizamos NGINX no frontend.
Dotnet core (kestrel no linux).
O upload é feito para o S3 da aws (já configurei as politicas de cors no bucket).

Comment: Não me parece q seja um problema de cors. De todo modo, já ativou todas as exceptions (mesmo handled) na ide?

Comment: Outro ponto, n relacionado à pergunta, mas se vc não fizer nada com a imagem (somente recebe na sua api e manda para a aws) vc pode fazer o upload direto para lá. Para isso vc consegue gerar um token temporário específico para um único upload.

Comment: Oi @tvdias obrigado pelo retorno, a sua dica é um excelente plano B, parece que quem ta limitando isso é o NGINX, ele nao demonstra estar pegando a configuração de limite client_max_body_size XMB. Iremos testar com o apache pra ver se surte efeito.

Comment: Irei ativar as exceptions em produção, não havia feito isso.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que está invertido, no "ConfigureServices" você adiciona o " services.AddCors();" e no "Configure" app.UseCors(opcoes => opcoes.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

Exemplo completo:

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MeuDbContext>(options =>
                   options.UseSqlServer(
                   Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

       
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(diretorio =>
            {
                diretorio.RootPath = "NomeDoSeuApp";
            });

            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opcoes =>
            {
                opcoes.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
            }).AddNewtonsoftJson(opcoes => {
                opcoes.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(opcoes => opcoes.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());


            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "NomeDoSeuApp");
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer($"http://localhost:4200/");
                }


            });
        }
    }
```